# spark join raises “Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans”

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a situation where I have a dataframe df
and let's say I do the following steps:

```py
 df1 = df

 df2 = df
```

and then write a query which uses D and E in the joins e.g

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1["column"] = df2["column"])
```

This is nothing but a self join which is widely needed in ETL. 
Why does spark not handle it correctly

I have seen many posts but none of them provide a work around.

UPdate:
If I load the dataframes df1 and df2 from the same s3 location and then perform the join the issue goes away. But when you are doing ETL it may not always be the case where we persist the data and then use it to avoid this scenario.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Y = D.join(E, on="column")`. The expression `E.column = D.column` doesn't have the same meaning in python as it does in sql - perhaps you meant `E.column == D.column`?

Comment: Try this before join **spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")**

Comment: Is enabling this: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")  a solution? I think something is wrong

Comment: Spark uses lazy evaluation, so when you say both of df1 and df2 are equal to the same df you won't get a deep copy of it, it will put only the reference of df. In order to do what you are trying to do you can create two tempViews from your df and use spark.sql to join.